# Random number based on a group and should not to equal to row number generated in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to Swap the records within a group and generated random number not to be same as Row_number. I cannot write Stored Procedure, it should be with SQL

Ex:

```
Row_number  Group     Desired O/pRandom_number  
1            1         3
2            1         4
3            1         2
4            1         1
1            2         2
2            2         1
3            3         4
4            3         5
5            3         3
```

I tried to calculate max and min within each group and generate the random numbers and everything looks fine. Issue is sometimes same random number will be assigned to row_number. I always want the random numbers and row_number to be always different

Comment: Why is it a problem if the random number is equal to the row number? What's the purpose of the random number?

Comment: As soon as you put a rule on your 'random' number (ie: it cannot equal row number), then by definition it is no longer a random number.  I second the questions asked by @DStanley

Comment: I have some other attributes in the table, I would like to swap the data between the group. Lag works well for me . I want to use random so that the Swapping logic is not the same on every run. With Random there are changes of row number and Desired  o/p being the same

Answer (score 1):

Just add 1 and use modulo arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       mod(row_number + 1, count(*) over (partition by group)) + 1 as desired
from t;
```

Comment: thanks ..Slight modification Worked:                                                                    
  select t.*,mod(row_number +1  , max(maxgroupval) over (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY dbms_random.value(mingroupval,Maxgroupval) )) + 1 as desired
from t;

Comment: @user2815115 . . . That doesn't guarantee that the result is different fro `row_number`, which your specifically requests.

Comment: Mod does not work.For Row Numbers ranging from 1 to 7 , the desired output is 1
2
1
2
7
1

Answer (score 0):

you dont want to use `row_number` in your solution, try to use `sum` analytical function with random ordering of rows.

I am not sure if it is allowed in your case or not but you can give a try.

> `Sum(1) over (partition by group order by dbms_random.value())`

Cheers!!